# Making a news app like Flipboard

Tags: ios, json, xml, uitableview, feed

I am trying to make a news app like Flipboard. I have all of the ideas for the design of the app and the content that can go in it, but I do not know what to do to retrieve all of the content for the app than displaying it. I know you probably need to use a UITableView along with some kind of news service to get data from with either a JSON or XML file to retrieve the content and display it. I have a couple of questions:

1. What is the best way to retrieve the content?
2. How can I display the content after retrieving it?

Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

1.What is the best way to retrieve the content?

- use json format for recive data,it's easy to refer keys and values.
- use MVC to manage recived data in app.

2.How can I display the content after retrieving it?

- use Table view or collection view to display list view in your app. Table view and collection view recuse cells in app.
- use image lazy loading for load images in app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question... Are there any news services that you recommend to get content from?

Comment: @PoKoBros check yahoo news services